# Text overflowing the answer box in exam.cls

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I am a beginner and would like to try latex for my lab reports. I am using exam for document class and I copied a template from elsewhere and now I try to a line which is overflowing the box.

[image: Looks like this]

My code looks like

```
\documentclass[a4-paper]{exam}
\printanswers
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question\textbf{Briefly describe the steps to request a loan from which your victim will benefit.}
            \begin{solution}
                We found two ways to benefit the victim.
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item We can manipulate the request of loan using a proxy tool (Burp Suite). We see that in our proxy request looks like 

                    \textcolor{red}{creditacc}=184830489\&\textcolor{red}{debitacc}=184830489{}\&\textcolor{red}{loan}=1234\&\textcolor{red}{period}=1\&\textcolor{red}{submit}=Request
                        \&\textcolor{red}{interest}=\textcolor{blue}{4.2}

                    Now we 
                \end{itemize}
            \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! LaTeX does not see where to break. There are several approaches to this. Just search for "LaTeX custom hyphenation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to just use `\newline` when you want the break to appear.

```
\documentclass[a4-paper]{exam}
\printanswers
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question\textbf{Briefly describe the steps to request a loan from which your victim will benefit.}
            \begin{solution}
                We found two ways to benefit the victim.
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item We can manipulate the request of loan using a proxy tool (Burp Suite). We see that in our proxy request looks like 

                    \textcolor{red}{creditacc}=184830489\&\textcolor{red}{debitacc}=184830489{}\&\textcolor{red}{loan}=1234\&\textcolor{red}{period}=1\&\textcolor{red}{submit}=Request
                        \newline
                        \&\textcolor{red}{interest}=\textcolor{blue}{4.2}

                    Now we 
                \end{itemize}
            \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My second suggestion would be we define the command `\&` new so that before every "&" there is possibility to break by inserting `\-` and we also use `sloppypar` that latex takes this opportunity regardless of the line is filled or not. I defined this new command locally but you could also define it in the preamble so that it affects everything or you define a new command for it and use that in your document.

```
\documentclass[a4-paper]{exam}
\printanswers
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question\textbf{Briefly describe the steps to request a loan from which your victim will benefit.}
            \begin{solution}
                We found two ways to benefit the victim.
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item We can manipulate the request of loan using a proxy tool (Burp Suite). We see that in our proxy request looks like 

                \begin{sloppypar}

                \let\oldand\&
                \renewcommand\&{\-\oldand}


                    \textcolor{red}{creditacc}=184830489\&\textcolor{red}{debitacc}=184830489{}\&\textcolor{red}{loan}=1234\&\textcolor{red}{period}=1\&{}\textcolor{red}{submit}=Request\&\textcolor{red}{interest}=\textcolor{blue}{4.2}
                \end{sloppypar}

                    Now we
                \end{itemize}
            \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I will wait for a while before marking this question solved, for a better method to overcome this problem.